# Recursive method which return the sum of the numbers from 0 to int incrementing by 1

Tags: recursion, methods, increment

Having trouble with a recursive method, it should output the sum of the numbers that increment by 1 to get to whatever is entered in the commandline arguments (sorry if that's worded a little weird)

for example, if 10 is inputed into the args, then it should output 55
Here is my code, the Method in question is sumofNumbers

```
public class RecursionMethods {


public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
if (commandlineArguments.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
   } 
else {
    Integer number = new Integer(0); // initializes the number
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) { // NumberFormatException
        System.out.println(exception + " is not a integer.");
        System.exit(1); // ends the program
    }
    String asterisk = asterisks(number); // return address for asterisks
    System.out.println(asterisk);

    String reverse = reverses(number);
    System.out.println(reverse);

    String counting = count(number);
    System.out.println(counting);

    int sums = sumofNumbers(number);
    System.out.println(sums);

 }

}

  public static String asterisks (Integer number) {
  if (number == 0) {
    return "";
} else {
    return "*" + asterisks(number - 1);
  }
}

public static String reverses (Integer number) {
if (number == 0) {
    return "0";
  }
  return number + " " + reverses(number - 1);
 } 

 public static String count (Integer number) {
if (number == 0) {
    return "0";
  }
 return count(number - 1) + " " + number;  
}       
  //here is where the recursion im having trouble with would go 
 public static int sumofNumbers (Integer number) {
   if (number == 0) {
    return 0;  
   }
  return sum(            






}
```

Comment: Just add the number to the sumOfNumber(number-1) and return if number reaches zero. :) Write it out each on a piece of paper to see how it would actually work. Make a table and chart out each variables value at each function call.

Comment: @anu Thank you very much, I figured it out thanks to you!

Comment: wc, Well done! glad you could figure it out all by yourself!